# After malloc the string how to compare it with null

Tags: c

a short question here.

I do know that if I declare something like

```
char* a[1024];
```

Then I can compare a[i] with null;

```
if(a[i])
```

However, if I malloc every element in a, then I may not do it...

The only way I can find out to compare it with empty is the following:

```
if(strcmp(a[i],"")!=0)
```

But I feel it is stupid and there must be more elegant way to do the comparison...

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

PS: 
I need to do malloc because I would do strtok. And I want to strcat something to the result, so I cannot just use a[i] as a pointer to the the result, but need to copy the content.

Comment: You want to check for a _null pointer_ by comparing with the macro `NULL`. There is no macro "null". And the `'\0'` terminator of a C-string is something completely different. Always check the result of `malloc` & friends!.

Comment: It might be better you state what you actually want to do, not what you think about to use. Your question text is not very clear what you actually want and there might be an XY-problem. E.g. there is no need per-se to use a `malloc`ed array for `strtok`. And note that C does not have a specific `string` type. So you `malloc` a `char`-array in the first place. It is treated as a string by semantics and convention only.

Comment: "However, if I malloc every element in a, then I may not do it..." – **what??** Why not…?!

Comment: "*Then I can compare a[i] with ...*" you cannot, at least as long the elements of  `a` had not been initialised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `strcmp` is fine, but you can also do

```
if ( a[i][0] == '\0' )
```

to see if a string is empty.

This assumes that you've put something in the string after calling `malloc`, e.g.

```
a[i] = malloc(...);
a[i][0] = '\0';
```

or

```
ptr = strtok(...);
a[i] = malloc(...);
strcpy( a[i], ptr );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `calloc` Instead of `malloc`. Thus your string chars are initialized to `\000` and you can test for it with `if (a[i][0])`.

Answer (score 0):

If you say you allocate every element of a with malloc, then you should have something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    a[i] = malloc(size);
```

Given this, why don't you test for the value of a[i]:

```
    if (a[i])
        // error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..`if(!a[i])` condition works when a[i] is NULL

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char *a[10];
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        a[i]=(char *)malloc(10);
    a[0]=NULL;
    a[1]="some text";
    if(!a[0])
        printf("a[0] is null value\n");
    else
        printf("a[0] is not null value\n");
    if(!a[1])
        printf("a[1] is null value\n");
    else
        printf("a[1] is not null value\n");
    return 0;
}
```